# Why I am getting each time "Flood Wait Error"?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
import asyncio
import time


async def main_send(client):
    time.sleep(1)
    for url_h in  ['@user1','@user2'.....,'@user50']:
        bot_entity = await client.get_input_entity(peer=url_h)
        await client.send_message(entity=bot_entity, message='message1')
        time.sleep(10)
    time.sleep(7)


async def main_get(client):
    lst = []
    for url_v in for url_h in  ['@user1','@user2'.....,'@user50']:
        bot_entity = await client.get_input_entity(url_v)
        async for message in client.iter_messages(bot_entity, wait_time=10, limit=60):
        lst.append(message)

api_id='...'
api_hash='...'
client = TelegramClient('for_otzv', api_id, api_hash)
with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main_send(client))
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main_get(client))
```

I have a very simple application for sending bulk messages. The documentation says "telegram api has a limit of 20 request per minute". But i use sleep function, and it should be OK.

What can be wrong? I  didnt terminate sessions.
The errors:

> telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.SessionRevokedError: The authorization has been invalidated, because of the user terminating all sessions (caused by GetHistoryRequest)

Comment: You're likely affected by https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/4051 or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The error you provided is `SessionRevokedError` and not `FloodWaitError`. It has already been explained clearly, already - "The authorization has been invalidated, because of the user terminating all sessions".

Comment: i didnt do that. so its not clearly(((